# Auto-delete older Atom version(s) in Windows

Tags: atom-editor

Atom is a cool editor per se, but among others, I have noticed something that annoys me a lot. Atom now auto-updates, yet there is still a problem. The old version is still in your hard drive and it is not auto-deleted.

Hence my question is simple: In Windows environment, how one can have all older versions to be auto-deleted instead of doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually remove any previous version installed using chocolatey. 
Steps are:

```
cup Atom  
cupinst Atom
```

Comment: Well yes essentially you first upgrade to the latest chocolatey atom version(previous versions didn't uninstall properly). Then just uninstall.

Comment: But the new Atom auto-updates ... yesterday I had 156, and today I had 156 and 157.

Comment: Are you using atom installer (preferred) or the chocolatey version.

Comment: From yesterday I use Atom installer.

Comment: So in that case just uninstall using second command the chocolatey version and you should be good to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66698/discussion-between-echetlaeus-and-nash-ag).

Answer (score 0):

You can also download an atom-windows.zip file from the releases page. The .zip version will not automatically update.

check [here](https://github.com/atom/atom)